# Mongo partial text match

Tags: mongodb, aggregate

Suppose I have a collection of subarrays as such:

```
{ _id: 1, thread: [{body: "Foo"}, {body: "Test"}]},
{ _id: 2, thread: [{body: "Bar"}, {body: "Lorem"}, {body: "Ipsum"}]}
```

I need search these and return only the matching `body` text in the sub array, with the following result:

```
{ _id: 1, thread: [{body: "Test"}]},
{ _id: 2, thread: []}
```

The following query does this:

```
db.threads.aggregate([
   {
      $project: {
         thread: {
            $filter: {
               input: "$thread",
               as: "thread",
               cond: {"$eq": {"$$thread.body": "Test"}}
            }
         }
      }
   }
])
```

However, I need to do a text search for anything **containing** a string, such as anything matching the letter `e`, case insensitive. The problem with `$eq` is it only returns exact matches.

I cannot figure out how to accomplish this.

---

As a note, I have a full text index on `thread.body`, if this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I have this so far:

```
db.threads.aggregate([
   {
      $project: {
         thread: {
            $filter: {
               input: "$thread",
               as: "thread",
               cond: {$gt: [{"$indexOfBytes": ["$$thread.body", "est"]}, -1]}
            }
         }
      }
   }
])
```

Seems lame. Looking for a better way to do it.